# Relay and React: Best way to pass props down

Tags: reactjs, redux, relayjs, relay

Say I have the following components.

```
Component_1
- Component_2
-- Component_3
--- Component_4
```

Component_1 is the parent of Component_2... and so fourth..

If `Component_1` is a Relay container and needs to pass a `viewer` object `prop` down to `Component_4` so it can create a fragment query whats the best way to do it?

1) Passing down the `viewer` `prop` down 3 components sounds tedious and worse if the component is further down the tree.

2) Is context recommended in this situation?

3) Redux/Flux - I think this is the most that makes sense

4) ?? use `QueryRenderer` ?? Create Route for `Component_4` ?? Other ??

Thank you

Comment: Right now I am passing the props down, but this is something I've wondered as well. I haven't tried a build with React for UI, Relay for Data, and Redux for state management.

I really love Relay so far, and think it makes sense to have fragments manage themselves... things become very self-contained. But the exhaustive data bubbling and passing was why I started using redux to being with. Now fetching is very optimized but I'm back to the same old hierarchy of managing state.